# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'quoteId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

The error full description:

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for  
  parameter 'quoteId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 
  'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResultGetQuoteSubTotal(Int32, System.String)' 
  in 'NI.Apps.WebSite.OliteBase.Controllers.QuotationController'. 
  An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type,
  or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The error never occured on my old web server. 
The old web server environment: Windows Server 2003(64bit)/IIS 6/.NET 4.
After i upgraded the environment to :Windows Server 2008R2/IIS 7.5/.NET 4, the error always was threw, but not all requests cause the error.

so this issue is a config issue?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikley config error. It looks like some incoming requests are missing `quoteId` parameter which is not optional. Most likly both servers will show this behavior if you play the same requests agains them (unless code is also different).

Comment: the code not changed, both are same, just upgraded the environments.
and i checked the trace log, the request is correct, and the json data in the request body too.

Comment: I found an error "The specified network name is no longer available." when read http request body.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when a mandatory parameter missing from the request being sent from browser.
Check for a parameter value expected to be passed to page.